# TFS web -Split Capacity for member if he has more than 1 project

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

TFS capacity-if a developer resource is setup on more than one project they will need to split the capacity if there is overlap.

Could you please provide me steps to perform this in TFS Web.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "Split" the capacity. If a person is in 2 teams at the same time, he can provide a capacity per day and slightly adjust the value, say 4 or 6 instead of 8. Then on the other team provide 4 or 2.

The capacity is saved at the Team level.

My recommendation is not to rely on the Capacity feature at all. I've never seen a client where this was used well and lead to real results.